# History.js or native history api?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, history.js

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js

In the "Notes on Compatibility" section it says it solves some browser bugs, but all browsers listed there are very old. Does that mean I can use the native API, if I don't need to support those browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. To find out if you can use something, the website [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is always very convenient. For example, for the History API, you'd get this table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=history. Which tells you almost every browser supports it in their newest version.